# Using condition in columns of data frame to generate a vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I have the following array:

```
  Year   Month   Day   Hour   
1   1      1       1    0
2   1      1       1    3
...
```

etc

I wrote a function which I then tried to vectorize by using apply in order to run calculations row-by-row basis, but it doesn't work due to the booleans:

```
day_in_season<-function(tarr){
  #first month in season
  if((tarr$month==12) || (tarr$month==3) ||(tarr$month==6) || (tarr$month==9)){
    d=tarr$day
  #second month in season
  }else if ((tarr$month==1) || (tarr$month==4)){
    d=31+tarr$day
  }else if((tarr$month==7) || (tarr$month==10)){
    d=30+tarr$day
  #third month in season
  }else if((tarr$month==2)){
    d=62+tarr$day
  }else{
    d=61+tarr$day
  }
  h=tarr$hour/24
  d=d+h
  return(d)
}
```

I tried

```
apply(tdjf,1,day_in_season)
```

but it raised this exception:

> Error in tarr$month : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

(I already knew about this potential pitfall, but that's why I wanted to use apply in the first place!)

The only way I can currently get it to work is if I do this:

```
days<-c()
for (x in 1:nrow(tdjf)){
  d<-day_in_season(tdjf[x,])
  days=append(days,d)
}
```

If there were only a few values, I'd throw up my hands and just use the for loop, efficiency be damned, but I have over 15,000 rows and that's just one dataset. I know that there has to be a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To vectorize your code, use `ifelse()` and`|` instead of `||`:

```
ifelse(
        (tarr$month==12) | (tarr$month==3) |(tarr$month==6) | (tarr$month==9),
        tarr$day, 
        ifelse((tarr$month==1) | (tarr$month==4), 
               31+tarr$day, 
               ifelse((tarr$month==7) | (tarr$month==10),
                      30+tarr$day,
                      ifelse(tarr$month==2, 
                             62+tarr$day,
                             61+tarr$day)
                       )
                )
        )+tarr$hour/24
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was fast! 

So, to clarify for future reference, it just basically did an elementwise boolean on each vector and returned a similarly sized vector? Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You might be surprised at how quickly a well constructed `for` loop can run. If designed well, it has about the same efficiency of an apply statement.

The proper`for` loop in your case is

```
tdjf$days <- vector ("numeric", nrow (tdjf))
for (x in seq_along (tdjf$days)){
  tdjf$days [x] <- day_in_season(tdjf[x,])
}
```

If you really want to go the apply route, I would recommend rewriting your function to take three arguments -- `month`, `day`, and `hour` -- and pass those three columns into `mapply`